# Create an ERC20 Stablecoin

Tags: solidity, tokens, ether, erc-20, stablecoins

How to create a stable coin with an ERC20 token contract ? Does it require contract to be modified ?
Are there some good practices or standards ?

Comment: Please check if this answers your question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57258/what-determines-the-price-of-the-erc-20-token-on-a-trading-exchange

Comment: So if I want a stable coin, I have to maintain a certain balance between supply and demand?

Comment: Theoretically yes.

Answer (score 1):

**Stablecoins** - regardless of the platform on which they've been implemented - generally fall into three broad categories:

- **Centralised / IOU** : A centralised controller holds an asset and creates IOUs that can be traded back in for the asset at a later date. Ex: TrueUSD & Gemini Dollar.
- **Collateralised**: Coin is issued in response to collateral being pledged. Value is kept stable by various means. Ex: DAI & Synthetix.
- **Algorithmic** (also called Seigniorage Shares ): Value of the coin is kept stable by algorithmically expanding or contracting the supply of coins in circulation. Ex: Terra & Ampleforth.

Now, like any other ERC20 Tokens, you can build your coin based on its nature.